# Java regex replace repeated characters (including non consequent)

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to write a regular expression to replace first among repeated characters in a string.

The catch is the repeated characters can also be non-consequent.

```
    Ex: 

    Input: abcdebg
    Replace by character:  x
    Expected Output: axcdebg
```

I have been trying to do this with a regular expression: `(.).*(\\1)`
But the result when i do a replace is: `axg`

Please suggest how i can achieve the expected result.

Thanks,
Sash

Comment: Could you explain _first among repeated characters in a string_ ?

Comment: @noob In the given example 'b' is a repeated character , i actually want to replace one of the occurence of 'b'

Comment: So you expected output is `axcdexg` ?

Comment: @noob No, expected output is either axcdebg  or abcdexg

Comment: @sash check Evan Knowles answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that you're matching the rest of the string up until the repeated character as well, which means it's also being replaced. You'll need to capture it and include it again.

So,

regex: `(.)(.*?\\1)`

Replace with (for x): `x\2`

Comment: Thanks for quick answer. I tried (.)(.*?\\1)  and the replaceFirst  still gives me wrong answer (same as mine):  axg

Comment: Bro, sorry i tried replaceAll with x$2 and it looks like it works. Let me try with couple of inputs and i'll accept your answer. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can use this lookahead based regex to replace a character only if same character is found ahead in input:

```
String str = "abcdebg";
String repl = str.replaceFirst("(.)(?=.*\\1)", "x");
//=> axcdebg
```